# Next-step validity check on fields where contents are validated by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I've been putting together a sign-up form that is essentially broken up into 3 parts; you fill out your name, email, username, etc. then your chosen options (colour, intro text, etc.), then your address details. Each of these steps has at least one field that utilises ajax to check its validity; i.e. checking for duplicate emails or usernames, suggesting alternate page titles, etc.

These ajax functions are triggered (after a brief delay) on `keyup input blur`, but it has only just occurred to me that I *also* want to validate the inputs when someone clicks to move on to the next step of the sign-up. The method I'd usually use is to trigger a `blur` on all fields of the current sign-up step and, if any have an `.error` attached, don't allow the user to move on; however triggering a `blur` on the fields with ajax listeners attached to them means that they don't *immediately* return an error.

Handily, I'm not using any kind of plugin - I've coded everything myself. When the ajax fields are checking the validity of their input, they do have a `.loading` class attached that will eventually turn into either an `.okay` or `.error` class, but on some screens there are 2-4 ajax-checked fields at once, so I need to wait for **all** of them to validate before moving on.

My current validation function is uber-simple:

```
$(document).on('click', '.step button.validate', function() {
    
    var currentStep = $(this).closest('.step');
    
    //  Let's try to trigger those errors ON PORPOISE
    
    currentStep.find('input, select, textarea').trigger('blur');
    
    if (currentStep.find('.error').length) {
        
        //  No dice.
        
        alert('This is bad, yo.');
        
        return false;
    }
    
    //  Everything looks hunky-dory; the form should submit as normal
    
    gotoNextStep();
});
```

**TL;DR** I'm trying to figure out how to 'wait' for all of my ajaxified fields to return a response before doing anything.

#### Worth noting:

The whole thing is wrapped inside one big `<form>` element. This doesn't get submitted with each step; only at the end, when each step has been provisionally validated. It (very basically) looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zVAxs/ (HTML markup only for illustration of structure).

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that it is what you are looking for, but $.ajaxSetup({async: false}) is what I can think of. Try using it at the start of your code and this way the code will wait for the answer of the request

Comment: Unfortunately as I'm not really waiting for the browser to *do* anything (simply sliding a div across the page, assuming validation has been successful) I don't think `async` is going to help me.

Comment: Then how about it:            if (currentStep.find('.error').length && !currentStep.find('.loading')) {

        //  No dice.

        alert('This is bad, yo.');

        return false;
    }

Comment: And you should add a setinterval which call the check function again and again until an error occurs or everything is okay. Then you should clear the interval. (sorry i cant write )any code as im on a phone and there is a bug so i cant add any newline characters...

Answer (score 0):

If you can call the ajax validation functions explicitly (not by triggering blur) then jQuery's 
when() function may help you: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

From jQuery sample:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/validation1.php" ), $.ajax( "/validation2.php" ) ).then(function( a1, a2 ) {
    // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the validation1 and validation2 ajax requests, respectively.
    // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
    gotoNextStep();
});
```

then() function is only executed if all ajax request have completed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I was looking at `when()` yesterday (as well as `promise()`) - I think the potential issue here is that, although multiple calls are being made, it's via Wordpress' ajax API  (wherein you can call a PHP function as an ajax action rather than a file), and each field may call a different action depending on its contents, **and** the scope of each call is set to the field calling it. I may look into this, but it might get pretty complicated.